# Problem with separating ContextProvider from app.jsx

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I just started using createContext/useContext and after successfuly implementing it I would like now to put it in seperate file. The problem is that i am getting error of too many re-renders and I don't really know whats the problem. Could you give me a clue what might be wrong? Below I have put context code,app.js and example of component where context is actually used.

```
***context***
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const DarkModeContext = createContext({
  isDarkMode: false,
  toggleIsDarkMode: () => {},
});

export const DarkModeContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isDarkMode, setIsDarkMode] = useState(false);
  const toggleIsDarkMode = setIsDarkMode((prev) => !prev);

  const value = {
    isDarkMode,
    toggleIsDarkMode,
  };

  return (
    <DarkModeContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </DarkModeContext.Provider>
  );
};
*** App.js***
import { useContext } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";
import MainSection from "../components/MainSection/MainSection";
import CountryPage from "../components/CountryPage";
import { Wrapper } from "./App.styles";
import { DarkModeContext, DarkModeContextProvider } from "./DarkModeContext";

function App() {
  const { isDarkMode } = useContext(DarkModeContext);
  return (
    <DarkModeContextProvider>
      <Router>
        <Wrapper dark={isDarkMode}>
          <Navbar />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<MainSection />}></Route>
            <Route
              path="/country/:countryCode"
              element={<CountryPage />}
            ></Route>
          </Routes>
        </Wrapper>
      </Router>
    </DarkModeContextProvider>
  );
}

***part of component***
import {useContext} from "react"
import { DarkModeContext } from "../../App/DarkModeContext";

export default function CountryPage() {
  const { isDarkMode } = useContext(DarkModeContext);
return (
    <CountryPageWrapper dark={isDarkMode}>
      <StyledLink dark={isDarkMode} to="/">
```

Answer (score 1):

What I'm noticing is that in `DarkModeContextProvider` you are calling `setIsDarkMode` on every render rather than wrapping that method in another function (you should also be passing the boolean value and not a function updating it). Try updating that line to:

```
 const toggleIsDarkMode = () => { setIsDarkMode(!isDarkMode) };
```

Assuming you meant the toggler to be a function, this should prevent your re-rendering loop as the setter is only getting called when the toggle is called into action.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a context provider and consume its value in the same component.

For example in `App` right now you have this:

```
  // ...
  const { isDarkMode } = useContext(DarkModeContext);
  return (
    <DarkModeContextProvider>
      <Router>
        <Wrapper dark={isDarkMode}>
  // ...
```

This doesn't work, because where is `useContext(DarkModeContext)` getting the value of its context from? It hasn't been rendered yet, until you render `<DarkModeContextProvider>` which happens *after* trying to get the value of `isDarkMode` from the context. This is backwards.

One easy way to to fix this could be to simply move your `<DarkModeContextProvider>` out of `App` and into where you *render* `<App />`. I assume you're using React DOM somewhere to render your app, so where you are using that try something like this:

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <DarkModeContextProvider>
    <App />
  </DarkModeContextProvider>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```